# Word is right aligning the first line of paragraph in bulleted list

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm trying to make a bulleted list in Word and for some reason it is forcing the **first line only** to be aligned to the right.

I am using Word 2010 and when I click on the relevant text it shows it as "left aligned" in the panels, so not sure why it is going to the right for?

If I take the bullets away it goes back to normal.

Example:

[image]

I have clicked on the bullet and I see a gray margin or something that is pushing it over; when I right-click I see `Adjust List Indents...`; played with the settings in there with no luck.

If I change the `text-indent` it messes up the lines below but doesn't touch the first line; if I change `Follow number with:` to `Space` it looks like this:

[image]

...if I change it to `Nothing` it looks pretty much the same as above, just no padding between the bullet and the text.

Any ideas!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you editing some existing document or are you using new one?

If you are editing existing document, it is possible that there are wrong styles.

Try to

- open new document
- write some bullet list
- select bullet list
- click "copy format" (usualy icon with brush)
- switch to your document
- select your bullet list.

This can restore style for selected text

Answer (score 6):

Turn on the ruler (Ribbon: "View", checkbox "Ruler"). Adjust the "First line indent" and the "Left indent" as desired. Your can grab and move them with your mouse.

[image: Indent markers in Microsoft Word's ruler]

Alternatively, you can pull down the bullets dropdown list and select "Customze Bulleted List". "Bullet position/Indent at" controls the position of the bullet. "Text position/Tab space after" controls the position of the text directly after the bullet. The "Text position/Indent at" controls the position of the following lines. Note that all values are relative to the page margin (and not relative to each other).

[image: Customze Bulleted List setting in Microsoft Word]

Also note that changing those settings only applies for the selected text, or the current paragraph if no text is selected.

Comment: There should be settings for these **within in the bullet presets**.

Comment: @Hannu: there are. Just added them to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Paragraph tab > Multilevel List > Define New List Style > Format > Numbering > More > 
Link Level to style > Select style > 
Define font > 
Set for ALL levels > 
Additional indent for each level > 0.02